# What do you call those recurring short videos at the beginning of each TV episode?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call those recurring short videos at the beginning of each TV episode that list key actors and members of the crew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called the [**title sequence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_sequence):

> A **title sequence** (also called an **opening sequence** or **intro**) is the method by which films or television programmes present their title and key production and cast members, utilizing conceptual visuals and sound. It typically includes (or begins) the text of the opening credits, and helps establish the setting and tone of the program.